# Why field is double when I print it in node.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have a issue. I created a field in "content types > article". Then I went to node.tpl.php and added next code:

```
<?php print render($content['field_like']); ?>
```

after that, I cleared cache and saw double field in my article.
I tried to hide this field in "manage display" but it didn't successful, my field disappeared at all.

I just want to render my field in a certain place in the node.tpl.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the field in the hide function.

```
hide($content['field_like']);
```

Do this after you have output your field but before you call render($content).

see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/hide/7.x